# How to prevent shards of new index from assigning on only a few nodes in Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, sharding

my index has 10 primary shards + 1 replica = total 20 shards

When a new daily index is created, shards tend to be allocated only to a few nodes with sufficient capacity.

It occurs *rejected operation* because these nodes take every incoming request.

I want to prevent shards from being concentrated in only a few nodes. (Including relocating disks by relocating existing shards)

- The cluster has a few nodes limited by a watermark and others with enough free space.

Also are there any APIs to spread shards across existing indexes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like some serious issue in your cluster which is not allocating the shards evenly on your cluster and this could lead to serious issues like

1. Unbalanced nodes, due to uneven distribution of shards
2. few loaded nodes which might go down and cause data loss
3. Performance issues
4. rejected requests in cluster

I guess you already found or near to finding the root cause of your issue, which is that some nodes are having high disk watermark which would be preventing the allocation of new shards on those nodes, I've written a [detailed explanation on what is disk watermark issue and how to solve it](https://opster.com/elasticsearch-glossary/elasticsearch-disk-watermark/)

Now coming to your question, of Any API to spread shards, good news is that yes, its available and called [cluster re-route API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/cluster-reroute.html), which you should use to spread the shards evenly in your cluster.

Comment: As you said, disk usage of some nodes almost `watermark.low` or `watermark.high`. but number_of_shards is similar between all nodes. 

But it is difficult to adjust the watermark according to your advice. because my data nodes use physical SSD, so increase watermark will occurs performance decrease.

Comment: @ssunno you could than use the reroute API as this is what you were looking for :)